# How to make ajaxRequest with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a simple PHP code:

```
<?php 
$numbers = range(1,100);
while(count($numbers)>3){
    unset($numbers[array_rand($numbers)]);
}
print "Numbers: ".implode(', ',$numbers)
?>
```

I want to create a HTML file that will use ajax to get the numbers my php code prints and show them on the HTML file.

This is my HTML so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "index.php", true);
ajaxRequest.responseText;
ajaxRequest.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I have to change to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: What's the issue currently?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'index.php',            
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (data)
            {
              $('body').html(data); // show data whereever you want - this case: on body
            }
        });
```

Comment: Be aware that you should include JQuery first

Comment: or on success: just work you data as you want.. use console.log(data) to see what you get from ajax

Answer (score 0):

[W3Schools PHP Ajax Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp)

***And also see to that If you are using IE browser you should be using ActiveXObjects.***